# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldlib /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack

Tags: c++, centos, dlib, lapack

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldlib
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
```

In the process of executing the dlib library code in centos7, up to'cmake' was executed.
However, the above error occurred during the make process. How do I fix it? (In ubuntu, only /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldlib problem occurred)

Comment: Do you have dlib, cblas and lapack?

Comment: I installed dlib.

Comment: And the other two libraries?

Comment: I haven't installed the other two libraries yet.
I will try the installation once and reply. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and solved it by installing this library on my ubuntu(20.04) OS:

```
sudo apt install libatlas-base-dev
```